# How does the "range interface" of golang run internally?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Phone interface {
    call()
    sales() int
}

type NokiaPhone struct {
    price int
}

func (nokiaPhone NokiaPhone) call() {
    fmt.Println("I am Nokia, I can call you!")
}
func (nokiaPhone NokiaPhone) sales() int {
    return nokiaPhone.price
}

type IPhone struct {
    price int
}

func (iPhone IPhone) call() {
    fmt.Println("I am iPhone, I can call you!")
}

func (iPhone IPhone) sales() int {
    return iPhone.price
}

func main() {
    var phones = [5]Phone{
        NokiaPhone{price: 350},
        IPhone{price: 5000},
        IPhone{price: 3400},
        NokiaPhone{price: 450},
        IPhone{price: 5000},
    }

    var totalSales = 0
    **for _, phone := *range phones* {
        totalSales += phone.sales()
    }**
    fmt.Println(totalSales)

}
```

i don't know the "range phones" run internally.i only understand that 'phone' is run in '[5]phone' order and i want to konw that golang how to recognizes iphone or  NokiaPhone.

Thanks , forgive me for my lame English.

Comment: http://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-interface-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface is a declaration of a *contract*, that is of the behaviour that implementing instances must support. By providing methods that are defined on the interface, a `struct` in Go automatically implements that interface and can be used in place of that interface wherever an interface based declaration is present. This is slightly different from many other languages such as Java or C++ where an instance must explicitly declare interfaces it implements and classes it extends. At runtime the code will get a concrete instance and execute a method of that instance. For the coder or for the declaration it does not matter, what matters is that instance will have a method as defined on the interface and that method can be called so the code can be written in generic interface terms.

This idea to *accept interfaces and provide structs/instances* is central for the inversion of control and dependency injection.

This is exactly what happens in you example. `NokiaPhone` and `IPhone` implement the `Phone` interface by providing methods declared on the interface `Phone`. When it comes to the loop, at each iteration a concrete instance is taken out of array, for that instance type the method asked for in the code is looked up, so the implementation now, and is executed. It works in the same way in Go, Java, C++ (with virtual methods) and many other languages that support either inheritance or interface/implementation pattern as Go does.